# SQL query to determine a scalar function's return type

Tags: sql-server

I know I can query to see a function's paramater data types like this:

```
SELECT st.name
FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.all_parameters ap ON ap.object_id = o.object_id
    JOIN sys.systypes st ON st.type = ap.system_type_id
WHERE o.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_GetPercent]') AND o.type = N'FN'
```

How can I programmatically check the return type for this functions? Can I join to another `sys` table to get that information?

I'm using SQL Server 2012, but I'm hoping for something that is backward compatible for 2008 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` system view to find the `return type` of `User Defined Function`.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same system views sys.all_parameters. On scalar functions, it gives a row with empty name for return type.
[See MSDN for sys.all_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-all-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT o.name AS ObjectName, st.name AS TypeName
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.all_parameters ap ON ap.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types st on st.system_type_id = ap.system_type_id
WHERE ap.name = '' -- Only returned values
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the f_dblog function in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES but this worked like a charm:

https://database.guide/find-out-the-data-type-of-the-columns-returned-in-a-result-set-in-sql-server/

```
SELECT 
    name,
    user_type_name,
    system_type_name,
    max_length,
    [precision],
    scale
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(

    'SELECT TOP 1
 [Current LSN],
 [Transaction ID],
 [Operation],
  [Transaction Name],
 [CONTEXT],
 [AllocUnitName],
 [Page ID],
 [Slot ID],
 [Begin Time],
 [End Time],
 [Number of Locks],
 [Lock Information]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)', 
    null, 
    0);
```