# Get return type of SQL Server function

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, a function is defined as [follows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
-- Transact-SQL Scalar Function Syntax
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ][ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type
 [ = default ] [ READONLY ] }
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS return_data_type
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN
        function_body
        RETURN scalar_expression
    END
[ ; ]
```

Where `return_data_type` can be `text`, a table (with a slightly different syntax), or almost any other data type.

Is it possible to retrieve the return data type without running the query?

<s>I know it's possible to do using `sp_describe_first_result_set`, but this executes the query and looks at the response.</s> **Edit: I was wrong. It is done through static analysis, but has a number of limitations associated with it.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to determine a scalar function's return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951501/sql-query-to-determine-a-scalar-functions-return-type)

Comment: I don't think `sp_describe_first_result_set` actually executes the statement(s).  Where do you see that mentioned?  It just considers all result paths.  Consider `EXEC sys.sp_describe_first_result_set N'select * into table2 from table1; select * from table1;'`.  When that is run, `table2` is never created.

Comment: @squillman Wow, it seems I made a faulty assumption about it. But with that said, the SP has limitations (for example, the use of a temporary table breaks it). The metadata for the return type is available in the header of the function declaration, I think it ought to be possible to get it from there.

Comment: Well, you can't use temp tables in functions anyway.  In any case, the duplicate should give you what you want.

Comment: @squillman I see. `sp_describe_first_result_set` works in that case, but it requires that I call the function in a valid way despite it not needing to run (I must provide it arguments). It's really going about it the hard way, instead of looking up the function definition and getting it from there.

Comment: @Fred This just returns `table` for non-scalar return types.

Comment: If you want something that covers both, `sp_describe_first_result_set` will give you what you want.  You don't have to pass it real values.  If it returns a single row and `name` is NULL then you know you have a scalar function.  If it returns more than one row then you have a table-valued function.  You'll have to play additional games with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` queries to get the schema for a TVF result set.

Comment: @squillman I see. I can work with that. But is there no way of getting it directly from the function definition? Static analysis seems excessive to me for this.

Comment: The linked duplicate appears to give you exactly what you ask for. You could of course parse the query definition text also.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can use `sp_describe_first_result_set`.

Or you can use the query from the linked duplicate and extend it with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT r.ROUTINE_NAME AS FunctionName,
       r.DATA_TYPE AS FunctionReturnType,
       rc.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName,
       rc.DATA_TYPE AS ColumnType
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS rc ON rc.TABLE_NAME = r.ROUTINE_NAME
WHERE  ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
ORDER BY r.ROUTINE_NAME, rc.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

That will give you the return information for both scalar-value functions and table-value functions, including schema information for the TVF result set.